# How to prevent ambiguous name on inner join with two references to same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables as follows (in mysql):

Table: invoice

```
#   Column Name
1   Id  
2   invoice_date    
3   invoice_no
4   consigned_to
5   invoiced_to     
6   ...
```

Table: company

```
#   Column Name
1   Id  
2   title   
3   ...
```

Both consigned_to and invoiced_to columns on first table are referencing `company.Id`.

What I am trying to achieve is a query with following columns

```
Column Name       Table Name
Id                (invoice)
invoice_date      (invoice)
invoice_no        (invoice)
consigned_to      (invoice)
consigned_title   (company.title)
invoiced_to       (invoice)
invoiced_title    (company.title)
```

I need unique column names for the consigned_title and invoiced_title columns, because I should be able to query those columns with titles from company table.

I managed to join single column like this with an alias:

```
SELECT invoice.*, company.title as consigned_title
from invoice 
INNER JOIN company ON invoice.consigned_to = company.Id
```

but could not managed to reference the same column from company for joining with the invoice.invoiced_to. Is it even possible?

Comment: Join to company again and alias the table.`from invoice 
INNER JOIN company ON invoice.consigned_to = company.Id INNER JOIN company c2 ON invoice.invoiced_to= c2.Id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need table aliases:

```
SELECT i.*, cc.title as consigned_title, ci.title as invoiced_title
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN
     company cc
     ON i.consigned_to = cc.Id INNER JOIN
     company ci
     ON i.invoiced_to = ci.id;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: It is probably obvious, but just asking to confirm: Is `company cc` a synonym for `company as cc`?

Comment: @SercioSoydanov . . . The `as` is generally optional for table aliases, and I don't recommend using them.  Using them consistently for *column* aliases is helpful (in case you forget a comma in the `select`), but I see no benefit for the `as` for table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the `id` column from the `company` table for the two use cases then you avoid the need to use range variables (OK, so SQL still forces you to **assign** range variables -- I'm using `c` and `i` in this case -- but you don't need to **use** them, which is an important distinction):

```
  SELECT invoice_no, consigned_title, invoiced_title
  invoice
  NATURAL JOIN
  ( SELECT id AS consigned_to, title AS consigned_title FROM company ) c
  NATURAL JOIN
  ( SELECT id AS invoiced_to, title AS invoiced_title FROM company ) i;
```